# Set axis x line to other origin than 0

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make a ybar axis that averages from the middle, but I cannot find a way to change the origin of the x axis.

This is what I want:

[image: The x line should start at 3]

This is what I have:

[image: The x line is starting at the bottom]

As you can see, I am trying to make an average. Can I do it like this or do I have to transform my data?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{data/singlecontrol.dat}\datatable

    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{variable},
    xtick=data,
    axis x line=middle,
    ymin=1,
    ymax=5
    ]

    \addplot table[x=X,y=averagejs] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Joystick}
    \addplot table[x=X,y=averagem] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Mouse}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trying to make an average" / "averages from the middle". From the screenshot, it looks like you just want the bars to start from y=3, instead of y=0, right? Is 3 the average of something?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Participants rate questions on a scale from 1 to 5. So the question is indeed: How do I start the x axis on y=3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ybar` plots always start from y=0. So what you'll have to do is change the tick labels on the y axis, so that 0 "looks like" 3, and subtract 3 from the data values, which you can do using a `y filter/.code`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    X averagejs averagem variable
    1 3.5 3.7 A
    2 4 4.4 B
    3 3.6 3.9 C   
    }\datatable

    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{variable},
    xtick=data,
    axis x line*=middle,
    enlarge x limits,
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-3}},
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick+3}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    ]

    \addplot table[x=X,y=averagejs] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Joystick}
    \addplot table[x=X,y=averagem] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Mouse}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Next up is trying to make those numbers into strings from a list.