# Set origin of y axis to 1

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

How to set the origin of y axis to 1?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[%
            ,xlabel=$N$
            ,ylabel=speedup
            ,axis x line=bottom
            ,axis y line=left
            ,scaled x ticks=base 10:-3
            ]
            \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(755,1.4) (1978, 1.6) (6273, 1.8) (12222, 2.1)};
            \addplot[very thick, color=blue] coordinates {(6273, 0.2) (12222, 1.2)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial. N is the leading dimension of the matrix. The black plot is for the case of one computer, while the blue one is for two computers.}
\label{plot:speedup}
\end{figure}

As we see in figure \ref{plot:speedup} ...

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT:

`ymin=1` will set the axis to 1, but the value below 1 won't be displayed! `ymin=1000` hides all the values!

Comment: `xmin=1`? (Or rather `xmin=1000` in this case.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for your comment. It seems that the `y` axis should be modified instead of the x one. Check my edit.

Comment: Is this what you're after then? [Set axis x line to other origin than 0](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60091) Edit: Taking from Jake's code, I guess `y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-1}}, yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick+1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}` does what you want.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I had seen this before posting and it seems too complex, I was expecting to find one or two commands that would do the trick. Or maybe, I just can't see how the link will work on my minimal example.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. no I did not see the edit, but my question was answered, thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, I see that. The solution is basically exactly the same,  though a bit more generalised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62431) what you want?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} % update to 1.12 if possible!
\pgfplotsset{%
    axis line origin/.style args={#1,#2}{
        x filter/.append code={ % Check for empty or filtered out numbers
            \ifx\pgfmathresult\empty\else\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-#1}\fi
        },
        y filter/.append code={
            \ifx\pgfmathresult\empty\else\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-#2}\fi
        },
        xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{\tick+#1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},
        yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{\tick+#2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    }
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}    
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        ,xlabel=$N$
        ,xmax=13000
        ,ylabel=speedup
        ,axis x line=middle
        ,axis y line=left
        ,axis line origin={0,1}
        ,scaled x ticks=base 10:-3
        ]
        \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(755,1.4) (1978, 1.6) (6273, 1.8) (12222, 2.1)};
        \addplot[very thick, color=blue] coordinates {(6273, 0.2) (12222, 1.2)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial]{Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial. N is the leading dimension of the matrix. The black plot is for the case of one computer, while the blue one is for two computers.}
        \label{plot:speedup}
    \end{figure}

    As we see in figure \ref{plot:speedup} ...  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Regarding this line of code though, `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} % update to 1.12 if possible!`, I had the editor in the latest version and I tried to update some other packages, but I still fail to be able to use 1.12. I am at Ubuntu, do you know any way to do this?

Comment: @gsamaras not important here. It works. If you want to update, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459